# Manifest file doesn't disable cache

Tags: html, caching, browser-cache

I need to disable cache for browsers however when I add a manifest file to the server, it displays old html.

Here's my manifest file (cache.manifest):

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# Cache manifest version 1.0

CACHE

#no cache

NETWORK
*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache manifest is for [offline applications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#offline) and controls the creation and use of a local copy of an application. It’s not really a cache, and it is very different normal caching. The HTML document containing the `manifest` attribute is always included in the application “cache”. This means that in supporting browsers, the HTML file, once loaded, will be stored locally and the local copy will be used in all subsequent accesses to its URL, without ever fetching it again from a server—unless the content of the manifest file changes.

To affect normal caching, use cache control tools provided by the server software or, if you cannot, use `meta` hacks. See [Caching Tutorial for Web Authors and Webmasters](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

Comment: thanks for the answer. how can I clean current cache?